# How to set headers using chromium kiosk mode?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, chromium, post, headers

I'm trying to create a dashboard on a Raspberry Pi using Chromium in Kiosk Mode. It works like a champ, except for one thing: I can't send headers.

The intention is that when the raspberry Pi starts, it'll automatically load up a certain link sending authentication headers with it.

Right now I use this in my autostart:

```
chromium --kiosk http://url_to_your_dashboard.com --incognito
```

Is there a way to set headers using this technique? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hey @czerspalace! Sadly no, I solved it by creating a chrome extension listening for the website. When the website is visited it sends the header with it. It’s a bit of a detour but it works!